# How to make text processing in a pandas df column more faster for large textual data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a large text file over 1GB of chat data (chat.txt) in the following format:

```
john|12-02-1999|hello#,there#,how#,are#,you#,tom$ 
tom|12-02-1999|hey#,john$,hows#, it#, goin#
mary|12-03-1999|hello#,boys#,fancy#,meetin#,ya'll#,here#
...
...
john|12-02-2000|well#,its#,been#,nice#,catching#,up#,with#,you#,and#, mary$
mary|12-03-2000|catch#,you#,on#,the#,flipside#,tom$,and#,john$
```

I want to process this text and summarize the word counts for certain keywords(say 500 words - hello, nice, like.... dinner, no) for each users separately. This process also involves removing all trailing special characters from each word

The output would look like

```
user   hello   nice   like    .....    dinner  No  
Tom    10000   500     300    .....    6000    0
John   6000    1200    200    .....    3000    5
Mary   23      9000    10000  .....    100     9000
```

This is my current pythonic solution:

```
chat_data = pd.read_csv("chat.txt", sep="|", names =["user","date","words"])
user_lst = chat_data.user.unique()
user_grouped_data= pd.DataFrame(columns=["user","words"])
user_grouped_data['user']=user_lst

for i,row in user_grouped_data.iterrows():
    id = row["user"]
    temp = chat_data[chat_data["user"]==id]
    user_grouped_data.loc[i,"words"] = ",".join(temp["words"].tolist())

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=[ "user", "hello", "nice", "like","...500 other keywords...", "dinner", "no"])
result["user"]= user_lst

for i, row in result.iterrows():
    id = row["user"]
    temp = user_grouped_data[user_grouped_data["user"]==id]
    words =  temp.values.tolist()[0][1]
    word_lst = words.split(",")
    word_lst = [item[0:-1] for item in word_lst]
    t_dict = Counter(word_lst)
    keys = t_dict.keys()
    for word in keys:
        result.at[i,word]= t_dict.get(word)

result.to_csv("user_word_counts.csv")
```

This works fine for small data, but when my chat_data becomes over 1gb, this solution becomes very slow and unusable.

Is there any part from below that I can improve upon which would help me process the data more faster?

- grouping textual data by user
- cleaning textual data in each row by removing trailing special characters
- counting words and assigning the word count to the right column

Answer (score 4):

You can `split` the comma-separated column to a list, `explode` to a dataframe by that column of lists, `groupby` name and the values from the exploded list, `unstack` or `pivot_table` the dataframe into your desired format and do some final cleaning on the multi-index columns with `droplevel()`, `reset_index()`, etc.

All of the below is vectorized pandas methods, so hopefully it is quick. Note: The three columns are [0,1,2] in the code below as I read from clipboard and passed `headers=None`

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'john', 1: 'tom', 2: 'mary', 3: 'john', 4: 'mary'},
 1: {0: '12-02-1999',
  1: '12-02-1999',
  2: '12-03-1999',
  3: '12-02-2000',
  4: '12-03-2000'},
 2: {0: 'hello#,there#,how#,are#,you#,tom$ ',
  1: 'hey#,john$,hows#, it#, goin#',
  2: "hello#,boys#,fancy#,meetin#,ya'll#,here#",
  3: 'well#,its#,been#,nice#,catching#,up#,with#,you#,and#, mary$',
  4: 'catch#,you#,on#,the#,flipside#,tom$,and#,john$'}})
```

---

Code:

```
df[2] = df[2].replace(['\#', '\$'],'', regex=True).str.split(',')
df = (df.explode(2)
      .groupby([0, 2])[2].count()
      .rename('Count')
      .reset_index()
      .set_index([0,2])
      .unstack(1)
      .fillna(0))
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df.reset_index()
df
Out[1]: 
2     0   goin   it   mary  and  are  been  boys  catch  catching  ...   on  \
0  john    0.0  0.0    1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0   0.0    0.0       1.0  ...  0.0   
1  mary    0.0  0.0    0.0  1.0  0.0   0.0   1.0    1.0       0.0  ...  1.0   
2   tom    1.0  1.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0       0.0  ...  0.0   

2  the  there  tom  tom    up  well  with  ya'll  you  
0  0.0    1.0  0.0   1.0  1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0  2.0  
1  1.0    0.0  1.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    1.0  1.0
```

You could also use `.pivot_table` instead of `.unstack()`, which saves you this line of code: `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()`:

```
df[2] = df[2].replace(['\#', '\$'],'', regex=True).str.split(',')
df = (df.explode(2)
      .groupby([0, 2])[2].count()
      .rename('Count')
      .reset_index()
      .pivot_table(index=0, columns=2, values='Count')
      .fillna(0)
      .astype(int)
      .reset_index())
df
Out[45]: 
2     0   goin   it   mary  and  are  been  boys  catch  catching  ...  on  \
0  john      0    0      1    1    1     1     0      0         1  ...   0   
1  mary      0    0      0    1    0     0     1      1         0  ...   1   
2   tom      1    1      0    0    0     0     0      0         0  ...   0   

2  the  there  tom  tom   up  well  with  ya'll  you  
0    0      1    0     1   1     1     1      0    2  
1    1      0    1     0   0     0     0      1    1  
2    0      0    0     0   0     0     0      0    0  

[3 rows x 31 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use `scikit-learn`, it is very easy with `CountVectorizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

s = df['words'].str.replace("#|\$|\s+", "")
model = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(','))

df_final = pd.DataFrame(model.fit_transform(s).toarray(),
                        columns=model.get_feature_names(),
                        index=df.user).sum(level=0)

Out[279]:
      and  are  been  boys  catch  catching  fancy  flipside  goin  hello  \
user
john    1    1     1     0      0         1      0         0     0      1
tom     0    0     0     0      0         0      0         0     1      0
mary    1    0     0     1      1         0      1         1     0      1

      here  hey  how  hows  it  its  john  mary  meetin  nice  on  the  there  \
user
john     0    0    1     0   0    1     0     1       0     1   0    0      1
tom      0    1    0     1   1    0     1     0       0     0   0    0      0
mary     1    0    0     0   0    0     1     0       1     0   1    1      0

      tom  up  well  with  ya'll  you
user
john    1   1     1     1      0    2
tom     0   0     0     0      0    0
mary    1   0     0     0      1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how much faster is this approach on a large DataFrame, but you can give it a try. First, remove the special characters and split the strings into lists of words, thus forming another column:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
df['lists'] = df['words'].str.replace("#|\$", "").str.split(",")
```

Now, group by the user), collect the lists into one lists, and count the occurrences with the `Counter`:

```
df.groupby('user')['lists'].apply(chain.from_iterable)\
                           .apply(Counter)\
                           .apply(pd.Series)\
                           .fillna(0).astype(int)
```